# public knowledge body visibility from the mobile view in a mobile browser

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, salesforce1-app, mobile

Knowledge body custom field does not show up when a knowledge article is clicked on a mobile device.

This body does show up when clicking on a non mobile device. The security does appear to be set up correctly.

Comment: I have recently worked on a project to expose knowledge to Public facing site and it is working fine with Mobile and Desktop. Is it public facing or authenticated community?

Comment: are you using PKB package? Have you dones customisations there?

Comment: Yes PKB packages is been used

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PKB package and you do not see any security settings which are different for mobile vs. desktop, I would strongly recommend raising a support case with Salesforce. I use KB & PKB all the time for universal access for mobile & non-mobile users and this has never been an issue.